# what is the near time?

Tags: vb.net, time, compare

Well,, guys i have project for ( **Food Times** ) ok ?
and i have 5 times for food

( **Morning** , **Midday** , **Sunset** , **Night** , **Midnight** )

---

- **Morning   :   03:20 AM**
- **Midday     :   12:05 PM**
- **Sunset     :    03:46 PM**
- **Night        :   07:33 PM**
- **Midnight  :   08:28 PM**

---

now i need put timer to check
It matches the current time with array times
If he finds any time of the array to the current time of PC he displays a message

---

I actually made an effort and wrote the code

```
    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Dim TimesArray() As String = {"03:20 AM", "12:05 PM", "03:46 PM", "07:33 PM", "08:28 PM"}
    Dim NamesArray() As String = {"Morning", "Midday", "Sunset", "Night", "Midnight"}
    Dim time = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay
    Dim q = TimesArray.Select(Function(t, i) New With {.Time = DateTime.Parse(t).TimeOfDay, .I = i}).Select(Function(d) New With {d.Time, .Diff = If(d.Time >= time, d.Time - time, New TimeSpan(24, 0, 0) + d.Time - time), d.I})
    Dim m = q.Min(Function(d) d.Diff)
    Dim r = q.First(Function(d) d.Diff = m)
    MsgBox("Food" & " " & NamesArray(r.I) & " " & "After" & " " & r.Diff.Hours & " " & "Hour" & " " & "and" & " " & r.Diff.Minutes & " " & "Minutes.")
End Sub
```

and **it works 100%** but needs **System.Linq.dll** in **.Net Fremwork 3.5** because of the **Select function**
That's why I want something that does not need this function ( **Select** )
and not need **System.Linq.dll** in **.Net fremwork 3.5**

Comment: What have you tried and what problem did you have. Show the code where the problem or error is.

Comment: Unfortunately, as written, this is just a requirement, not a programming question. As already stated, we need to see specifics, so please edit your question to show what you've tried, where you're stuck, expected output, actual output, errors ,etc. Otherwise, this will likely be closed as "too broad" or "unclear what you're asking"

Comment: i edit my post now

Comment: You've changed your question but you still haven't shown us that you have made any effort to implement those requirements. SO is not a tutorial site or a code-writing site. It is for help with specific problems. If you haven't even tried to write any code then you haven't encountered any specific problems yet.  Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: ok bro, i edit my post see now

Comment: any help guys???

Comment: If you are trying to avoid using the 3.5 framework (and LINQ) what framework are targeting for use?

Answer (score 0):

This should for what you want. At each timer tick, the sub iterates through your array and checks the current time against the array and the time difference is less 0 hours and 0 minutes, the messagebox is shown.

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Dim TimesArray() As String = {"03:20 AM", "12:05 PM", "03:46 PM", "07:33 PM", "08:28 PM"}
    Dim NamesArray() As String = {"Morning", "Midday", "Sunset", "Night", "Midnight"}

    For i As Integer = 0 To TimesArray.Count - 1
        Dim tempDateTime As Date = Date.Parse(TimesArray(i))
        Dim tempTimeDiff As TimeSpan = tempDateTime.Subtract(DateTime.Now)
        If tempTimeDiff.Hours = 0 And tempTimeDiff.Minutes = 0 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Food " & NamesArray(i) & " After " & tempDateTime.Hour & " and " & tempDateTime.Minute & " Minutes.")
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: This is not what I need

Comment: "i need put timer to check It matches the current time with array times If he finds any time of the array to the current time of PC he displays a message" needs clarifying then.